# Connect Azure AppService to Application on a VM over HTTPS

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I need to connect our Azure AppServices to an Application running on a Azure VM. This application requires HTTPS and the AppServices have an application installed that will point to the HTTPS Address of the application on the VM.

I tried creating a Self-Signed Certificate on the VM and adding this to SSL of the AppService (exported .pfx) but that failed as I believe it only adds that to the Trusted Personal store/there is no access to the Trusted Root Store on a Azure AppService.

The Azure environment has a .local domain setup. Do I need to get a CA Certificate for my Application on the VM and install these on the Azure AppServices or do I have to a public domain name instead in order to have SSL communication between the Azure AppServices and my HTTPS application running on the Azure VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this scenario you need to place both VM and App service in same VNet and then establish a Point to Site Connection, then by default it will be encrypted. 
check the link below for more details: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/02/01/create-a-vnet-and-access-an-azure-vm-hosted-within-it-from-an-app-serivces-web-app/

Comment: I added an internal DNS Server to a VNET the VM and App Services shared. However, for HTTPS, certificates are required and AppServices require CA Certs

Comment: you can add SSL certificate anytime to your supported Azure resources check this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server